# Unable to pass a parameter from a closure to a function in Swift

Tags: swift

I recently started learning Swift and got a question about closure.
I tried to pass the parameter of driving to func travel and got an error message: Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '() -> String'

Can anyone kindly advise? Appreciate!

```
import UIKit

let driving = { (place: String) in
    print ("I'm going to \(place).")
}


func travel(action: () -> String) {
    print("I'm getting ready to go.")
    action()
    print("I arrived!")
}

travel(action: driving("London"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`driving` is a closure of type `(String) -> Void`

`driving("London")` is a function call expression, calling that closure, passing it the argument `"London"`. The result of this expression is the result of the closure, which is `Void` (a.k.a. the empty tuple, `()`).

That `()` argument value isn't compatible with the parameter, which is expected to be `() -> String`.

Answer (score 0):

`driving` is a closure, but `driving("London")` is a closure invocation that returns `()`.

If you need the closure to have the variable that holds the value "London", i.e. if you want closure to capture ("close") it, you can do it with a function:

```
func makeAction(place: String) -> () -> String {
   { "I'm going to \(place)." }
}

let drivingToLondon = makeAction(place: "London")

// drivingToLondon() will return "I'm going to London"

travel(action: drivingToLondon)
```

You might also want to update `travel` to print the return value of the closure, since it returns `String`:

```
func travel(action: () -> String) {
    print("I'm getting ready to go.")
    print(action())
    print("I arrived!")
}
```